# Facebook Graph API /me/home Friends Posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the home feed for a user, but all the posts by my friends are no longer there (only feeds by Pages show). This happened near the v2.2 release. Are we no longer able to get a user's news feed with their friends posts? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome&version=v2.0

Comment: It looks like friends' news are back on the /me/home end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like friends' news are back on the /me/home end point

Answer (score 0):

friend permissions are gone with v2.0 - so i assume this happened in April 2014 when v2.0 was introduced, for privacy reasons you can´t get anything from friends who did not authorize your app too. Wouldn´t it be weird if you could just see the posts of friends in the stream of the authorized user, without the friends being able to control this?

Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog